# Keep an SSH connection persistent through waking and suspending of computer

Tags: ssh, suspend

Here are my informations:

- I have an SSH connection I use as a SOCKS5 proxy. It's annoying to have to reinitialize it everytime I wake-upon-computer.
- I've set `ServerAliveInterval` to `60` in `~/.ssh/config`. I have not permission to add `ClientAliveInterval` and even if did I it would have exactly the same effects.
- The specific error message I get is "Broken pipe". `screen` or `tmux` wouldn't help here, I would have to attach everytime which brings us back to square numero uno.
- `autossh` doesn't seem to work. I ran `autossh -M 0 -DPORT alias` and I see it in task manager, but the SSH connection doesn't seem to restart not even after waiting 5 minutes.

I've read plenty of questions that say to use one of the three above options, but none of them address waking and suspending. I cannot put it in some bash initialization script because I only want it to happen once (when I log into the computer). But at the same time, I want my SSH connection to stay alive if it dies WHILE I'm on the computers. What combination of effects than I utilize to achieve my cause?

Comment: How long do you expect a TCP connection to stay alive? When you put your computer to sleep, I assume it stops sending TCP traffic...

Comment: Broken pipe messages are usually caused by overzealous firewalls, detecting/deciding inactivity and cut the connection. Unfortunately, your ssh client or server don't have much chance to fight against those, as they look for keyboard/mouse input as a sign of activity and lack of it causes session termination. My solution is on the client side. If it is windows, I use `autootkey` to whip up a quick  macro to type `ls -l` into the terminal in question and hit enter. Fortunately, the firewalls I worked with can not discriminate between human input and a robotic one

Comment: you should try instant transmission.

Comment: `autossh` correctly resume my connexion (with a tmux inside) with `ServerAliveInterval 30` and `ServerAliveCountMax 3` after being suspended an entire night. Maybe try with `ServerAliveCountMax`?

Answer (score 3):

### Connection persistence

Having persistent connection requires support on the server side. This is not available in current openssh server(and does not look like it will be).

The client part was implemented years ago, the famous [`UseRoaming`](https://www.qualys.com/2016/01/14/cve-2016-0777-cve-2016-0778/openssh-cve-2016-0777-cve-2016-0778.txt) feature, that was dropped weeks ago from openssh. The feature never worked and was [one big security vulnerability](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110639/how-exploitable-is-the-recent-useroaming-ssh-problem). It might have worked with `appgate.com` SSH server, but I have heard about that one for the first time with this vulnerability.

Client/Server Alive Intervals are working only within the TCP keepalive and of course if you didn't change IP address between suspend and wake up.

### Scripts after network comes up

I would consider a solution for your case to use `ifup` script (script that is run after the network interface is brought up). It might look somehow like this in `/sbin/ifup-local`, where you can do your SOCKS5 start:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [[ "$1" == "eth0" ]]
then
  ssh -DPORT alias
else
  #DO_NOTHING
fi
```

Don't forget to make the script executable `sudo chmod +x /sbin/ifup-local`. You might also add more checks and stuff to that script, differentiate network interfaces or whatever. [Source](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-run-startup-script-automatically-after-network-interface-is-up-on-centos.html)

Answer (score 0):

(somewhat tangential answer, but it could be useful in your situation)

You can try running ssh via UDP based OpenVPN (if your firewall permits this). This kind of works, though delays when reconnecting are quite large (a minute or so).

However, if you are able to use it, try [mosh](http://mosh.mit.edu). It has been designed with connection persistence from the very beginning.

Comment: `mosh` is fine for shell, but will it help for SOCKS proxy?